# Best way to create Object using String variable Android

Tags: java, android, string, object

i have a question using a String with this format in Java(Android):

> "{ key1 = value2, key2 = value2 }"

What's the best way to convert this String into Object?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: A string is already an Object.  What exactly do you need?

Comment: I need to store this data and set it in InputTexts, this string can comes with more key=values

Comment: Ok, a map is your best bet.  I'll write an answer

Comment: I think his real value may be more complex (maybe json) and therefore it may be a bad idea to just split at `,`

Comment: If the Strings are indeed JSON, then the following question will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HashMap<String, String> getMap(String rawData) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    String[] pairs = rawData.split(","); // split into key-value pairs
    for(String pair: pairs) {
        pair = pair.trim(); // get rid of extraneous white-space
        String[] components = pair.split("="); 
        String key = components[0].trim();
        String value = components[1].trim();
        map.put(key, value); // put the pair into the map
    }
    return map;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = getMap("key1 = value1, key2 = value2");
String valueForKey1 = map.get("key1"); // = value1
```